# How to implement git log <branch>..FETCH_HEAD in libgit2?

Tags: git, branch, libgit2

I need to present user a list of commits that are fetched, but not yet merged. This means finding wanted branch in FETCH_HEAD and showing `git log <branch>..FETCH_HEAD`. How to approach the last step in libgit2? I should stop `git_revwalk*` at first commit common to both `<branch>` and to the pseudo-branch created by the sha tip stored in FETCH_HEAD. Does this mean that I first need to load whole `<branch>` into memory? Or maybe there is other method of stopping `git_revwalk*` (that was started at FETCH_HEAD tip)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to show the commit id contained in `FETCH_HEAD` by  [`git_revwalk_push`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/master/include/git2/revwalk.h#L109)ing it.  Then you would [`git_revwalk_hide`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/master/include/git2/revwalk.h#L150) the commit id of the branch that you want to stop at.

This should revwalk only the range `hide..show`.